# In Python, how can I store table and sort it based on one column?

Tags: python, sorting, data-structures

I have a HTML table with columns

(`Id|Name|Address|Phone`)

I'm importing using [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and iterating over the rows.

The source data in table is out of order, but I would like to print out all this information in sorted order by ID.

What sort of data structure do I keep these values in (different list for each column?) and how can I sort the remaining 3 columns based on ID?

Comment: You might want to use a list of lists. For sorting see: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no great batteries-included way to do that (that I'm aware of). You could try to do it with the builtin containers, maybe something like:

```
data = [(some, headers, go, here),
        (data, from, first, row),
        (data, from, second, row),
        ... ,
        (data, from, last, row)]
```

and then build a custom key to sort it, like:

```
import operator

data = data[0] + sorted(data[1:],key=operator.itemgetter(col_num_to_sort_by))
```

But that's kind of ugly. It may be more maintainable to create a custom class that handles all that itself.

```
import operator

class Table(list): # inherits from list since it's just a list of lists
    def __init__(self, headers, rows_of_data):
        self.maxcellwidth = 0
        self.headers = headers
        for cell in self.headers:
            self.maxcellwidth = max(len(str(cell)), self.maxcellwidth)
        for row in rows_of_data:
            self.append(row)
            for cell in row:
                self.maxcellwidth = max(len(str(cell)), self.maxcellwidth)
    def sort_by_column(self, sort_by):
        """Sort by column and return a new Table"""
        return Table(self.headers, sorted(self, key=operator.itemgetter(sort_by)))
    def sort_by_columnip(self, sort_by):
        """Sort by column in-place"""
        self.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(sort_by))
    def __str__(self):
        return_value = list()
        header = "|".join(["{0:{1}}".format(header,self.maxcellwidth) for header in self.headers])
        return_value.append(header)
        return_value.append("-" * len(header))
        for row in self:
            return_value.append("|".join(["{0:{1}}".format(cell,self.maxcellwidth) for cell in row]))
        return "\n".join(return_value)

# TEST
>>> headers = ("one","two","three","four")
>>> data = [('1','2','3','5'), ('5','6','7','4')]
>>> table = Table(headers, data)
>>> print(table)
one  |two  |three|four 
-----------------------
1    |2    |3    |5    
5    |6    |7    |4 
>>> table.sort_by_columnip(3)
>>> print(table)
one  |two  |three|four 
-----------------------
5    |6    |7    |4    
1    |2    |3    |5
```